# jqgrid treegrid example in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to use JQGrid-Treegrid in my MVC 4 project and I need to use free/open source version of the grid. I couldn't find any documentation on how to use JQGrid-Tree grid with ASP.NET MVC.

There are plenty of documentation/example available on http://www.trirand.net/ but that's for their license version, not for open source version. All documentations for open-source version of grid are available on PHP, unfortunately I don't know PHP :(

I would appreciate if someone in this great community could please give me a link to example/documentation on how to use JQGrid-TreeGrid with ASP.NET MVC 4

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on the www.trirand.net site that has a demonstration for ASP.NET MVC. Here is the standard grid:

http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/

And here is the link for the TreeGrid:

http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqtreeview/

There are tabs at the bottom of the page that have examples of the Model, View and Controller to make the grid functionality work.

Hope it helps.